# Unable to trap SIGINT signal in a background shell

Tags: bash, signals, child-process, sigint, bash-trap

I am unable to trap a signal when running in a child / background process.

Here is my simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "in child"

trap "got_signal" SIGINT

function got_signal {
  echo "trapped"
  exit 0
}

while [ true ]; do
    sleep 2
done
```

When running this and later do

```
kill -SIGINT (pid)
```

everything works as expected, it prints `trapped` and exits.

Now, if I start the same script from a parent script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "starting the child"

./child.sh &
```

Then the child does not trap the signal anymore.... ?

After changing to use SIGTERM instead of SIGINT, it seems to be working correctly... ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `bash` manpage on OSX (but it should be the same in other versions) has this to say about signal handling:

> Non-builtin commands run by `bash` have signal handlers set to the values
>   inherited by the shell from its parent.  When job control is not in
>   effect, asynchronous commands ignore `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` in addition to
>   these inherited handlers.

and further on, under the `trap` command:

> Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot
>   be trapped or reset.

Since scripts don't use job control by default, this means the case you're talking about.

Answer (score 5):

Per your note:

```
Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset.
```

I have noticed that ZSH does not ignore the signals sent back and forth between parent and child process, but bash does. Here's the question I posted myself:

[Trapping CHLD signal - ZSH works but ksh/bash/sh don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560245/trapping-chld-signal-zsh-works-but-ksh-bash-sh-dont)