# bash trap propagated to command with custom signal handler

Tags: bash, signals, bash-trap

In my script I'm trapping signals in the usual way.

```
function on_stop {
  echo 'On Stop'
  sleep 10
  echo 'Signalling others to exit'
  trap - TERM EXIT INT
  kill -s INT "$$"
}

./executable_with_custom_signal_handling &
pid=$!
trap 'on_stop' TERM EXIT INT
wait
```

If `sleep` is used instead of `./executable_with_custom_signal_handling` everything works as expected. Otherwise, `./executable_with_custom_signal_handling` receives signal immediately in parallel with `on_stop`.

I am wondering does it have something to do with a custom signal handling in the executable?

```
signal(SIGINT, handler)
```

Any workarounds known?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bash: Why can't I set a trap for SIGINT in a background shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061694/bash-why-cant-i-set-a-trap-for-sigint-in-a-background-shell)

Comment: Why does it work with `sleep 2000 &`?

Comment: I tried without background, still not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

By default, [the shell runs backgrounded commands with SIGINT (and SIGQUIT) *ignored*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11).

Your backgrounded `sleep` is not interrupted by the Ctrl-C SIGINT to the process group, then, because it never sees the signal.  When your custom executable installs a new signal action, replacing SIG_IGN, that executable *will* receive the SIGINT.